# Dynamically choose branch when building repo in Bamboo

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo

Within Bamboo I have several linked repositories. Each one of these repositories are connected to a specific branch, which you have to set through Bamboo's web interface. Is it possible to dynamically choose the branch without having to go in and change the linked repo branch every single time?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, Bamboo supports branches, both manually added and automatically detected without new repository needing to be created.  You just need to let it know where you keep branches in your repo.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html

Scroll down to managing plan branches in bamboo.  They reference feature branching at the top of this article, but you don't have to be using that paradigm to get some use out of the branching support in bamboo.

Comment: Is it possible to do this dynamically with a variable? My ultimate goal is to read in a JSON file that contains the various branch names of each repo I need. I want to be able to use a branch name from the JSON file as a variable that corresponds to a repo branch I want to pull.

Comment: You might be able to do this using bamboo build variables, see: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-variables-task-687213475.html.  I haven't done anything like that personally, so whether you could use the variable after you'd defined it to match a branch to read from I'm uncertain.

Comment: Bamboo allows you to run scripts of your choice, so you could write a bash script or node script that parses the json and checks out your specified branch, then run the rest of your build logic.